# CakePHP use $this in view function

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

In my CakePHP3.6 project  I use the [TreeHelper](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tools/blob/master/src/View/Helper/TreeHelper.php) to create my menu.

In my view (**pages/index.ctp**) I use:

```
<?=$this->Tree->generate($pages,['alias'=>'title']); ?>
```

Which creates a basic unordend list.

With TreeHelper I can use a callback function to change the value inside the list items:

```
<?
$this->Tree->generate($pages,['alias'=>'title','callback'=>'myFunction']);
function myFunction($obj) {
    $id = $obj['data']['id'];

    $return = $this->Html->link('Edit',['action' => 'edit', $id]);
    $return .= $obj['data']['title'];

    return $return;
}
?>
```

I want to use the HtmlHelper (ie `$this->Html->link`) to create links, but it gives me this error:

> Using $this when not in object context

Is there a solution/ workaround so I can use the HtmlHelper inside the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a global function use an anonymous function.

```
$this->Tree->generate($pages, [
    'alias' => 'title',
    'callback' => function ($obj) {
        $id = $obj['data']['id'];

        $return = $this->Html->link('Edit',['action' => 'edit', $id]);
        $return .= $obj['data']['title'];

        return $return;
    }
]);
```